# Error Insertando datos en PostgreSQL a través de CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, codeigniter, netbeans-8.2

Estoy teniendo problemas en la inserción de datos en mi BD de postgres, soy bastante nuevo en esto por ende se que puede ser una pregunta básica pero no consigo la respuesta. Cree un schemas de nombre codig con los parametros indicados al final.
Estoy usando CodeIgniter 3.1.9, PostgresSQL 9.4 y Netbeans 8.2. Ya probe la conexion a postgres y funciona sin problemas más a la hora de insertar me arroja este error (desconozco si tiene algo que ver con el schemas)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vista

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>c_persona/btnGuardar" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Cedula:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtCI" placeholder="99.999.999"></td>
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Nombre:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtNombre" placeholder="XXXXXXXXX"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Apellido:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtApellido" placeholder="XXXXXXXXX"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Correo:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="email" name="txtCorreo" placeholder="XXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Fecha de Nacimiento:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="date" name="dateNac" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label><h2>Usuarios</h2></label></td>                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Nickname:</label></td>
                    <td><input type="email" name="txtCodigoUsario"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Clave</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="txtClave"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="submit"  value="Guardar">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controlador

```
   public function btnGuardar() {
    //datos tabla persona
    $parametros['cedula'] = $this->input->post("txtCI");
    $parametros['nombre'] = $this->input->post("txtNombre");
    $parametros['apellido'] = $this->input->post("txtApellido");
    $parametros['correo'] = $this->input->post("txtCorreo");
    $parametros['fecha_nacimiento'] = $this->input->post("dateNac");
    //Datos tabla usuario
    $paramUsuario['codigo_usuario'] = $this->input->post("txtCodigoUsario");
    $paramUsuario['clave'] = $this->input->post("txtClave");

    $this->m_persona->btnGuardar($parametros);
}
```

Modelo

```
public function btnGuardar($parametros) {
    $campos =array(

      'nombre'=> $parametros['nombre'],
      'apellido'=> $parametros['apellido'],
      'correo'=> $parametros['correo'],
      'cedula'=> $parametros['cedula'],
      'fecha_nacimiento'=> $parametros['fecha_nacimiento']            
    );

    $this->db->insert('persona',$campos);

}
```

BD PostgreSQL

> -- Table: codig.persona
>
> -- DROP TABLE codig.persona;
>
> CREATE TABLE codig.persona (   id_persona serial NOT NULL, nombre
>   character varying(100),   apellido character varying(100),   correo
>   character varying(100),   cedula character varying(100),
>   fecha_nacimiento date,   CONSTRAINT pk_id_persona PRIMARY KEY
>   (id_persona) ) WITH (   OIDS=FALSE ); ALTER TABLE codig.persona
>   OWNER TO postgres;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por defecto, PostgreSQL considera que el schema al que te refieres es `public`, y en `public` no existe la tabla `persona`.

Tu sentencia, por tanto, debiera ser:

```
INSERT INTO codig.persona (...) VALUES (...)
```

en vez de

```
INSERT INTO persona (...) VALUES (...)
```

Comment: Justo estaba probando eso mismo ya que andaba leyendo la documentación y efectivamente el error esta en el modelo, cuando hago enfasis a la tabla, ya que como tal no existe la tabla persona en public, por ende mi codigo quedaría

$this->db->insert('codig.persona',$campos);

Comment: No estoy seguro de que eso vaya a funcionar. Puede que por debajo intente hacer `INSERT INTO "public"."codig.persona" (...)`. Es posible que tengas que configurar el parámetro ` schema` al instanciar la conexión.